# It seems that it does not know the saga run method

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I create a sample cra redux-saga app , but when i run it , it have an error:

[image]

It seems that my app not know redux-saga correctly , because of "createSagaMiddleware" is white in import phrase and run method is not clickable:

[image]

**Updated:**

rootSaga:

[image]

userSaga:

```
import {call, put, takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';

const apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

function getApi(){
    return fetch(apiUrl, {
        method:"GET",
        headers:{
           'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .catch((error) => {throw error})
}

function* fetchUsers(action) {
    try{
        const users = yield call(getApi);
        yield put({type:"GET_USERS_SUCCESS" , users:users});
    }catch (e) {
        yield put({type:'GET_USERS_FAILED' , message:e.message});
    }
}

function* userSaga() {
    yield takeEvery('GET_USERS_REQUESTED' , fetchUsers);
}

export default userSaga();
```

Comment: can you post the `rootSaga` function please?

Comment: I update it . @LouayAlosh

Comment: try changing `export default userSaga();` in last line to `export default userSaga;` It might be the cause of the error

Comment: Wow, what a ridiculous mistake :) . thanks a lot @LouayAlosh